# Aptana's css autocomplete doesn't update itself

Tags: autocomplete, aptana

I'm doing an web project and all pages have the .php suffix. I started with a single css (style-default.css) file and the auto-complete worked perfectly. Now I changed that css filename (to custom.css) and added some more css files (Foundation 3 framework).

The strange thing is when typing `class="..."` the autocomplete only shows me options for the custom.css although it displays the name "style-default.css" and no suggestions at all for the "foundation.min.css". I checked and both files are *included in the build* despite I can't *build* a web project. **Is there any way to refresh the auto-complete?**

I even tried removing the project and importing it again, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out... Aptana auto-complete apparently can't read *.min.css. I included the *.css instead and the suggestions appeared. Still, the outdated filenames looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This is an Eclipse core bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=89859.